# SQL Function Error: Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: t-sql, sql-function

I have a very simple function to calculate and format a floating point number:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetUrbanHours 
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@driverID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result float = 0

SELECT @Result = 
    FORMAT(
        SUM(CONVERT(float, 
            CONVERT(bigint, RouteSummary.UrbanNightSeconds + RouteSummary.UrbanDaySeconds))/(60*60)),
        '##,##0.00')
    FROM RouteSummary WHERE DriverID = @driverID

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Result

END
```

When I call the function with a given parameters, I get the following errors:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 9
Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

When I extract the SELECT statement and print @Result, I get the expected result.  What is my problem here?

**EDIT**

I have rewritten the function as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetUrbanHours 
(
@driverID int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SumSeconds bigint
DECLARE @SumHours float

SELECT @SumSeconds = 
    SUM(RouteSummary.UrbanNightSeconds + RouteSummary.UrbanDaySeconds)
    FROM RouteSummary WHERE DriverID = @driverID
IF @SumSeconds != NULL
BEGIN
    SET @SumHours = CONVERT(float, @SumSeconds) / (60*60)
    SET @Result = 
        FORMAT(@SumHours, '##,##0.00')
END
RETURN @Result

END
```

When I give a parameter that returns rows from the RouteSummary Table, I get NULL. When I give a parameter that returns no rows, I get "Msg 8115, Level 16, state 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."  What is wrong now? Also is there a way to identify the line in the function the error message refers to? And why can't I step into the function with the SQL Studio debugger?

Comment: Try changing return type to BIGINT

Comment: what is output of select when you print it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first error do not assign a value to the variable.  The second error is caused by your use of the TSQL FORMAT statement.  The format statement returns a VARCHAR not a FLOAT. See this link for information on the FORMAT command.
[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)